# Decorating actors with some actions

Tags: scala, akka

I read about dangerous case [there](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html#Dangerous_Variants).

Now, I'm working on an extension which is supposed to trace incoming messages. I.e. when a message arrive I have to notify some external system that the message's arrived.

Is it safe to create actor object within another actor and pass it to props factory?

```
class HandlingActorWrapper(val decoratee: Actor) extends Actor {

    override def receive: Receive = {
       System.out.println("Message recieved");
       decoratee.receive
    }
}

object HandlingActorWrapper{
    def props(actor: Actor) = Props(new HandlingActorWrapper(actor))
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
       //handling messages
    }
}

class SomeActor extends Actor {
   var child : ActorRef = _

   override def preStart() = {
                                                                    //>>|HERE
      child = context.system.actorOf(HandlingActorWrapper.props(new MyActor))
   }
   //other
}
```